# Conditional Check in The Loop's Parameters

Tags: loop

I have several loops each of them built to display a certain category in different style, based on user's input (they're within shortcodes). Now I want to "merge" these (or just 1 of them) loops with the loop to display recent posts, regardless of the category.

Currently this is my code (to display post from a certain category):

```
$args = array(
  'category_name' => $category, 
  'showposts' => $numposts, 
  'order' => $order
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
// loop's usual stuff
```

As I said, they are inside shortcodes, so, $category, $numposts (number of posts) and $order are user's input (shortcode's atts)

Anyway, to display the recent posts, all I have to do is take away the category part. However, when I did that from the shortcode's "side" (by not filling the shortcode and not displaying it), the loop is broken. I suppose it is because I have declared "category" within the query parameters.

I've tried:

```
$args = array(
   if (!empty($category)) {
    'category_name' => $category,
  }
  'showposts' => $numposts, 
  'order' => $order
);
```

but of course, it is throwing an error :P. Well, I guess at least it is better explaining what I am trying to achieve.

My question: Is there anyway around this or should I build a new shortcode / loop, specific to just display the recent posts?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Longer code:

```
function boxed_category($atts, $content) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      "category" => '',
      "numposts" => '-1',
      "order" => 'ASC'
    ), $atts));

    $output = '';

    $args = array(
      'category_name' => $category, 
      'showposts' => $numposts, 
      'order' => $order
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();
```

well, not many difference - function name because it is originally made to display a certain category (inside "boxed" - CSS) - I want to turned this shortcode to have a "Recent Posts" option. I'm going to need more atts, but first, need to figure out how to "get rid" of $category from the query should a user chose "Recent Posts" option.

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code.

Comment: Just edited to original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would change

```
$args = array(
      'category_name' => $category, 
      'showposts' => $numposts, 
      'order' => $order
    );
```

to

```
$args = array(
      'showposts' => $numposts, 
      'order' => $order
    );

if ( $category )
     $args['category_name'] = $category;
```

This way you never pass an empty `category_name` parameter as a query arg.

Comment: Thanks Helga.. D**n, I really need more experience in PHP :P

Answer (score 0):

> ...need to figure out how to "get rid" of $category from the query
>   should a user chose "Recent Posts" option

This is barely a WordPress question, if at all, but just don't use `category` if you don't have one.

```
$args = array(
  'showposts' => $numposts, 
  'order' => $order
);
if (!empty($category)) {
  $args['category_name'] = $category;
}
```

The same for any of your other optional arguments.

Comment: Thanks s_ha_dum, I voted Helga's because hers is on the top, but I believe yours would work as well.

Comment: @Mario88 : Actually, answers [aren't necessarily ordered oldest to newest](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127231/ordering-of-answers-for-a-question) but answers shouldn't be selected by that criteria anyway. Choose the best answer and upvote any helpful ones.

Comment: I said that because both of the answers are basically doing the same thing. Somehow, Helga's appear first (although, I remember that both you and Helga answered at the same minutes - both were "15 minutes ago" - at the time I checked). I don't know if, maybe there is an upside / downside for each of the answers, but I decided to go according the order. In anyway, I greatly appreciate your answer / responds :) EDIT: Tried to upvote your answer (as it is correct and helpful) but apparently I need 15 points. I'll remember it for the next time.